# Error in getting geolocation in ionic application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation

I am building an ionic application in which i need geolocation of the device. For that i am using [cordova-plugin-geolocation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation) and my code is this :

[image]

But i am getting this error again and again.

[image]

I searched a lot of stuff on internet but do not found anything useful. Do anybody has any idea or suggestion in order to solve this problem ?

It seems like google no more support HTTP but is it even possible to make my ionic application HTTPS ?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova plugins don't work on browser.

If you want to test it on browser you have to add

```
cordova plugin add browser
```

And then to run your ionic app use

```
cordova run browser
```

not every plugin will work on cordova browser. Further you might have to emulate or build the app and test it out.

**Update**: You need to call all functions one the device is ready.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    //All your code here.
}
```

Before your device is ready you won't fetch any value of your location.

Cheers!

Comment: i am getting the same error in mobile phone also... :(

Comment: Is your loctaion service on?

Comment: Is your app prompting request for location access? @gauravmehla

Comment: @gauravmehla i've updated my answer. you need to call everything inside  onDeviceReady function. Also your code should be in app.js inside $ionicPlatform.ready function. I've tested this it's working. :)

Comment: Yes.. it prompted for location access

Comment: Still getting the same error.. :https://gist.github.com/gauravmehla/db556a603e8fc6d797f2150ba0e69ad0

Comment: i am testing this application in emulator